# Help making a singly linked list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

This is for homework but please know that I have looked online for help (such as http://www.sethi.org/classes/class_stuff/cis435/others/notes-java/data/collections/lists/simple-linked-list.html) and my textbook but I am still having some issues.

Any help would be appreciated...

Right now I'm trying to just insert values in but nothing is working. Whether it's the first item, whether it's being added as the last one, or somewhere in between.

```
Node header = null;    // First element of list.
Node back  = null;    // Last element of list.

public void insert(int i, double value){ //insert value before i-th element
  Node e = new Node();
  e.num = value;
  Node curr = header;
  for(int x=0;x<i;x++) {
   if (i == 1) { //we want to insert as first thing
    if (size == 0) { //its the FIRST time we add something
     header.next = e;
     e.next = back;
     break;
    } else if (size == 1){
     e.next = header.next; //i.e. the second thing in the list
     header.next = e;
     break;
    } else {
     e.next = header.next.next; //i.e. the second thing in the list
     header.next = e;
     break;
    }
   }
   else if (x == (i-1)) {
    e.next = curr.next;
    curr.next = e;
    break;
   }
   curr = curr.next;
  }
  size = size+1;
 }
```

Not really sure why it isn't working.

Thanks!

Comment: This is too much code for an `insert at i`. Two things: 1) construct the node like so if you can: `Node node = new Node(val);`, 2) Make the logic simpler. Break it down into: A) Find the node after which to insert, or throw an exception/return null (whatever the convention is), B) Perform an insertion (This should be a method of the node class itself, in fact. You should split the responsibilities between the `Node` and the 'LinkedList` classes). By the way, the standard names for the LL should be "head" and "tail" and not "header" and "back". Think snake, not Excel. What the hell is a header?

Comment: @Harnish - great comment.  +1 just for "This is too much code for an insert at i".  Spot on.

Comment: I was about to say "Homework with code, big huge +1 for the rare occasion". Then I didn't see an error message...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, people who are still learning to program make things far more complicated then they need to be. I did it when I was learning java, I still do it when I am just getting into a new language, and students that I have marked find new and amazing ways to do it. You have more going on in your insert then there needs to be, for example, a method that inserts a value at a specific index should not check if it's the first item to be inserted (not saying it shouldn't check bounds). Here is the pseudo code of what I would do.

```
insert(index, value)
    if index>size
        throw null pointer
    traverse to index -1 //lets call this nodeI
    create newnode and set value
    set newnode.next to nodeI.next
    set nodeI.next to newnode
    increase size.
```

Couple of handy hints for you, you should have a function to get an element from the link list, something that returns a node? public node elementAt(int index) for example? use that to traverse the linked list. If you want to append to the Linked list, try this

```
append(value)
    insert(size-1,value)
```

and if you want to insert at the beginning? same idea

```
insert(value)
    insert(0,value)
```

Comment: Alternatively tail-recurse and let the `Node` do all of the work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. implement java.util.List
2. Think about generics
3. Read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Start with "insert at the end" before you think about "insert at i".

Answer (score 1):

1. In the line `e.next = header.next.next` what would happen if `header.next` points to a 'null'?  Is it possible to get there?
2. What are the corner cases you have to deal with and have you taken them all into account?
3. Can you start with the simplest case first, adding either an element to the front or an element to the back?  Then use those functions to implement the insert?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a simple program, which will be useful for you guys, I am also learning Java, please bear with me for any mistakes, but this program works fine.

I am posting a very simple singly linked list program in Java, which I tried out today.
I hope it will help all.

**LinkList.java**

```
class LinkList
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  Node node = new Node(1);
  node.addAtLast(2);
  node.addAtLast(3);
  node.addAtLast(4);
  node.addAtLast(5);
  node.printList();
 }

}
```

**Node.java**

```
class Node
{
 private int data;
 private Node link;

 public Node(int mydata)
 {
  data = mydata;
  link = null;
 }

 public void printList()
{
 System.out.print("|"+data+"|"+"->");
 if(link != null)  
 {
//recursive call
 link.printList();

 }
else
 {
//marking end of list as NULL
 System.out.print("|NULL|"); 
 }
}

public void addAtLast(int mydata)
{
 if(link == null)
 {

  link = new Node(mydata);
 }
 else
 {
  link.addAtLast(mydata);
 }

}

}
```

**OUTPUT :**

The below is our output

> |1|->|2|->|3|->|4|->|5|->|NULL|

Comment: Post your code in the answer rather than linking it.